# Youtube API returning more views than is listed on native

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When using this API call:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==UCaGKtfnhSkDsIbcyVVUOL6A&start-date=2017-06-27&end-date=2017-06-27&metrics=views,comments,likes,dislikes,shares,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,averageViewPercentage,annotationClickThroughRate,annotationCloseRate,subscribersGained,subscribersLost&dimensions=day&filters=video==qstWdXxFmcU

We are getting an incorrect amount of views.  For example we have 173 views for the video linked below via the API but native only shows 123 views:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qstWdXxFmcU

Comment: This is still not resolved and I am still experiencing this issue to this day.

Comment: This is STILL not resolved as of this very day.  Can someone from Youtube API dev look at this and explain the discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

From the [view metrics section](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#views) of Youtube analytics doc, it indicates that views are reported in the same manner as [watch time report](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1714329?ref_topic=1714326&guide=1714169) which tell us the following :

> Note: Analytics views data is based in Pacific Standard Time, updated
>   once a day, and has a delay of up to 72 hours. The numbers you see in
>   Analytics reports might be different from the numbers you see on the
>   video page, channel page, Video Manager, or other sources.

Comment: Sure that would make sense if there were more views on native than there are from the API, but how would the time delay make any sense for the API having **more** views?  You cannot unview a Youtube video.

Comment: [How video views are counted](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2991785) describe that `To verify that views are real and accurate, YouTube may temporarily slow down, freeze, or adjust the view count, as well as discard low-quality playbacks`

Comment: How temporary is temporary though?  This video is weeks old and the view count is not up-to-date.  Not to mention, the value is off by about thirty percent, which is an unacceptable difference for data analysts that pay for our product.  I find it incredibly hard to believe this is working as designed.